# UnsafePointer to Last Array Element in Swift

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I'm attempting to use the `vDSP_conv` function in Accelerate [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_conv). One of the arguments to `vDSP_conv` is a `const float *__F` that "needs to point to the last vector element". I'm not extremely familiar with using pointers in Swift, so I'm at a loss for how to create a pointer to the last array element of a Swift array.

Can anyone provide some insight?

/** EDIT **/

Function specification that I am trying to call:
`func vDSP_conv(_ __A: UnsafePointer<Float>, _ __IA: vDSP_Stride, _ __F: UnsafePointer<Float>, _ __IF: vDSP_Stride, _ __C: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, _ __IC: vDSP_Stride, _ __N: vDSP_Length, _ __P: vDSP_Length)`

So far, I have this code. I need `y` to point be a pointer to the last element in the array as `conv` starts at the end of the array and progresses to the front

```
public func conv(x: [Float], y: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    var result = [Float](x)
    let inputLength:Int = x.count
    let outputLength:Int = inputLength + y.count - 1
    vDSP_conv(x, 1, y, 1, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(inputLength), vDSP_Length(outputLength))

    return result
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: @CodeDifferent please see edit in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withUnsafeBufferPointer()` gives you a pointer to the array's
contiguous storage, from which you can calculate a pointer to
the last array element:

```
func conv(x: [Float], y: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    var result = [Float](count: x.count - y.count + 1, repeatedValue: 0)

    y.withUnsafeBufferPointer { bufPtr in
        let pLast = bufPtr.baseAddress + y.count - 1
        vDSP_conv(x, 1, pLast, -1, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(result.count), vDSP_Length(y.count))
    }

    return result
}
```

(Note that your calculation of the result array length was not correct.)

Examples:

```
print(conv([1, 2, 3], y: [4, 5, 6]))
// [ 28 ] = [ 1 * 6 + 2 * 5 + 3 * 6 ]

print(conv([1, 2, 3], y: [4, 5]))
// [ 13, 22 ] = [ 1 * 5 + 2 * 4, 2 * 5 + 3 * 4 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and thanks for also bringing up the issue with the result array!